# help with constrained optimization setup in R

Tags: r, optimization

I have a function which parameters I wish to optimize. As a simplified example, the function looks something like this:

```
F <- function (d)
    {
            num_iterations <- 10
            function_data <- c(1,3,5,7,9,11)
            rslt <- 0
            di_1 <- 1
            di_2 <- length(function_data) 
            for (i in 1:num_iterations)
            {
                 di <- d [di_1:di_2]
                 rslti <- function_data - di

                 rslt <- rslt + sum(rslti)

                 function_data <- rslti
                 di_1 <- di_1 + length(function_data)
                 di_2 <- di_2 + length(function_data)

            }

            return (rslt)
    }
```

where d is the vector with length equals to: `num_iteration * length(function_data)` .

So I wish to maximize function F and have optimized values of `d`, consisted from values of `d` for every iteration. The problem is that I have to constrain the optimization process in a way, that in particular iteration inside function, `di` must be smaller or equal to `function_data` (`di <= function_data`). Moreover the scalar result of the function should be positive number.

I have difficulties how to specify the condition `di <= function_data` since the `function_data` changes every iteration. I have played around with *optim* and *constrOptim* in R, but I think it is not possible to set constrain like this in *constrOptim*.

So I would like to ask how (or if) this constrained optimization problem can be set up in R. I would be really grateful for any help, comments, code snippets or optimization package recommendations. Please have a patience with me, I am a newbie in this.

Thank you.

Comment: In the first iteration you have `di <- d[0,6]`. Is `d` a matrix? In R, the first row or element in a vector is indexed as `1`, using the index `0` will return an empty object.

Comment: If you give the mathematical expression of your objective function it may be easier to understand it and the type of constraints. Are the constraints determined beforehand as an upper bound to the values in `d`?

Comment: @javlacalle I am sorry, d is a vector and 0 was incorrect index, I have already fixed it. To second comment, my objective function is 
F, it is kind of simulation for ten periods. During this periods values of `function_data` are changing in a way that result of one iteration (period) is the input to the next iteration. And I need to have optimized values of d for every period. I am not sure if it is possible to formulate mathematical expression of this function. About beforehand values of d, it can be beforehand determined only for first period so `d[1,length(function_data)] <= function_data`

Comment: The indexing `d[di_1,di_2]` is used for matrices (it would take the element in the `di_1`-th row and `di_2`-th column). Doesn't it return the error "incorrect number of dimensions"?

Comment: I am really sorry, it was a typo, it have to be `di <- d [di_1:di_2]`. It is just chopping input vector d into smaller vectors - one for every iteration (period) step. I fixed it in question. Thank you.

Comment: `function_data` is of fixed length but `di <- d [di_1:di_2]` is of varying length at each iteration. The lengths of `function_data`and `di`do not match at all iterations. Are you aware of this when substracting these vectors `rslti <- function_data - di`?

Comment: I think this is not true, `di` is of same length every iteration, and that is the length of `function_data`. Input argument `d` have to be of length `length(function_data)*num_iteration`. In this example case `di` is in every iteration of length 6 (same as `function_data`) and `d` have to be of length 60. I checked it.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the lengths are the same. The length of `d` is 60, now I see a little what the objective function does.

Comment: I don't know how to handle this issue. Just a couple of comments. The method "L-BFGS-B" in `optim` allows you to include upper bounds to the parameters; the problem is that there is now way to define a priori those bounds. You could try splitting the problem in `num_iterations=10` subproblems. You can take each iteration in the loop as a subproblem. Each subproblem will optimize the function with respect to a subset of six parameters. But the solution for the first subproblem would return minus infinite values for the parameters; maybe you can adapt the idea by including also lower bounds.

Comment: Be also aware that by default `optim` minimizes the objective 
function. It may be more convenient to return the negative `-rslt` in function `F` so that the negative of your original function is minimized, which is equivalent to maximize the original function.

Comment: Thank you very much _javlacalle_ for comments. I have also thought about splitting it into subproblems for every iteration, I am just not sure if optimized values for every period will lead to optimal values for whole simulation.